# How to set PHP document root in httpd.conf

Tags: php, xampp, apache

I have a site in a subdirectory e.g. `root/sites/testsite/` and I would like the php variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to be `root/sites/testsite/` and not `root`, how would I do this being in mind I am on shared hosting?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is automatically set to the `DocumentRoot` configured in your Apache `VirtualHost` configuration entry. This will be the directory pointed to by the URL `/` on your domain.

You will need to change the code to use a different variable to calculate the base directory, such as one hard-coded in a config file. You may also be able to use the Apache `SetEnv` directive in a `.htaccess` file to pass in a variable - e.g. `SetEnv BaseDir root/sites/testsite/` would result in `$_SERVER['BaseDir']` being set to the string `"root/sites/testsite/"`.

Alternatively, you could assign a new value to the variable at the beginning of the script, in order to "spoof" its value (for instance if using 3rd-party code that relies on this variable).

Comment: [Edit: this was in answer to a comment which I think has been deleted] An .htaccess file with just that in would be exactly that - a file with that one line in, called .htaccess, and placed in the directory where your PHP is running. Assuming your host is set up to do so (most shared hosts are), Apache will read that file, process the SetEnv, and that's it!

Comment: Thanks, I'll go give it a go! If you stick the .htaccess file in a high directory will it apply to all php files below it?

Comment: Yes. The official Apache documentation on .htaccess files is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html